# Spring Boot GraalVM Native Image compilation crash on ch.qos.logback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-logback

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.5, Java 17, GraalVM 22.3.1.

It crash during compilation on error:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.5:process-aot (process-aot) @ app ---
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@60b4beb4 - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [LOG_MAXSIZE_IS_UNDEFINED]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7fcf2fc1 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
    at net.example.app.appApplication.main(appApplication.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.lambda$prepareApplicationContext$0(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor$AotProcessorHook.run(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.prepareApplicationContext(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
2023-04-12 14:31:36.686+0000 ERROR [                                ] 937 [           main] ---  822:g.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@60b4beb4 - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [LOG_MAXSIZE_IS_UNDEFINED]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7fcf2fc1 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
    at net.example.app.appApplication.main(appApplication.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.lambda$prepareApplicationContext$0(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor$AotProcessorHook.run(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.prepareApplicationContext(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@60b4beb4 - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [LOG_MAXSIZE_IS_UNDEFINED]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7fcf2fc1 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@60b4beb4 - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [LOG_MAXSIZE_IS_UNDEFINED]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7fcf2fc1 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
    at net.example.app.appApplication.main(appApplication.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.lambda$prepareApplicationContext$0(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor$AotProcessorHook.run(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.prepareApplicationContext(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@60b4beb4 - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [LOG_MAXSIZE_IS_UNDEFINED]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7fcf2fc1 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
    ... 34 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

This is my `logback-spring.yml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32968#issuecomment-1303213314 -->
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_PATH" source="logging.file.path" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_MAXSIZE" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_MAXHISTORY" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_TOTALSIZECAP" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.total-size-cap" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) [%32X{requestId}] %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(---){faint} %clr(%4line:%-40.40logger){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/mwhs.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) [%32X{requestId}] %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(---){faint} %clr(%4line:%-40.40logger){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/mwhs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <!-- https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy -->
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>${LOG_MAXSIZE}</maxFileSize>
                <maxHistory>$100</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>${LOG_TOTALSIZECAP}</totalSizeCap>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mwhs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
            <artifactId>pebble</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:10.1.0</buildpack>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

and `application.yml`:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: INFO
        stat: DEBUG
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql: TRACE
    net.example.app.app: DEBUG
  file:
    path: /tmp/app
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-history: 90
      total-size-cap: 2GB
```

I compile using:

```bash
mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
rm -rf target/native
mkdir -p target/native
cd target/native
jar -xvf ../app.jar
touch META-INF/native-image/argfile

native-image -H:Name=app \
@META-INF/native-image/argfile \
-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
-H:TraceClassInitialization=true \
-H:IncludeResources=".*" \
--initialize-at-build-time=\
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty\
,org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder\
,org.slf4j.LoggerFactory\
,org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger\
,ch.qos.logback\
-cp .:BOOT-INF/classes:`find BOOT-INF/lib | tr '\n' ':'`
```

and run application using:

```bash
java -jar -Xmx64m app.jar --spring.config.import=application.yaml"
```

so my configuration of logging is external. Is it problem?

I'm totally lost. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is it you full `logback-spring.xml`? Did you use any `RollingFileAppender`?

Comment: @samabcde no, it's not. I've just update my question and put my full `logback-spring.xml`

Comment: I suspect the problem is `application.yml` not included as resources, try add `-H:Log=registerResource:` to see what is actually included.

Comment: The failure appears to be happening during the `process-aot` goal of Spring Boot's Maven plugin which happens before native image compilation, but you've said that you're compiling the native image manually. Can you clarify the steps that are necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I've added my `pom.xml`. Can you see what I do bad?

Comment: I moved `logging.*` to internal (classpath) config and it crash on another error. How can I have `logging.*` in external file?

Comment: Why are you using `spring-boot:build-image` which builds a container (Docker) image for your application and then also manually running native image compilation? Have you considered using the [approach that's described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_the_native_profile) instead? In short, you'd add the `org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin` plugin and then build the native image using `mvn package -Pnative`. If this approach doesn't work, you'll need to describe exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I removed `buildpacks` from my `pom.xml`. I don't need docker image, I need only nativeimage (binary). It works - thank you.
But I still don't know how to fix `logging.*` in yaml file loaded using `--spring.config.import=application.yaml"`. Is it possible?